# Android Jack: Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.util.function.Consumer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, lambda

Getting this on android studio 2.2.

Does anyone have a workaround?

My app build file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "acme.cb2"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
}
```

edit: modifid the *main* build file to include answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/5753091/mohammadreza-khalifeh - but this did not help

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'org.hidetake:gradle-ssh-plugin:2.4.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xbootclasspath/a:" + System.properties.get("java.home") + "/lib/rt.jar"
        }
    }
}
```

edit: adding:

```
options.compilerArgs.each { println 'option: '+it}
```

prints out:

```
option: -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre/lib/rt.jar
```

It looks like the space in the path might cause a problem?

edit: trying:

```
options.compilerArgs << "\""+"-Xbootclasspath/a:" + System.properties.get("java.home") + "/lib/rt.jar"+"\""
```

does not work either.

Comment: Looks like this relates to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41735756/cannot-use-lambda-functions-in-android-with-java-1-8 Still waiting for a working answer :(

Comment: it probably is. iirc, i got something to work for a while, but it broke when i upgraded android studio. i did not really need lamndas, so i gave up and stuck with 1.7. i used my own definition consumer and used anonymous inner classes.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after adding `Guava` library to my dependencies.

Solution was to downgrade lib version from `com.google.guava:guava:21.0` to `com.google.guava:guava:20.0`.

Also, I'm using  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.5.0-alpha-preview-01`

**EDIT:** As you don't use this library please try to change:

- in project `build.gradle`

  - classpath from `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.5.0-alpha-preview-01`
- in app `build.gradle`

  - from  `compileSdkVersion 24` to `25`
  - from  `buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"`to `25.0.2`
- in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

  - change version to `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/gradle-3.5-20170213202653+0000-all.zip`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but... I don't see Guava in OP's dependencies.

Comment: Java 8 support: compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android'

Answer (score 0):

add this in your build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xbootclasspath/a:" + System.properties.get("java.home") + "/lib/rt.jar"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.+'
```

and

```
minSdkVersion 25
```

Answer (score 0):

upgrading android studio, the following seems to work  (but it's *really* slow now):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "acme.cb2"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
       }
    }
    dexOptions {
        //javaMaxHeapSize "4G"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
}
```