# Error:W3CHttpCommandCodec.java: Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled

Tags: java, android, appium

> Build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.andeb.appiumproject"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}



compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Error :

> *Error:W3CHttpCommandCodec.java:181-182: Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown
>   interfaces are java.util.function.Predicate*

**Gradle Console**

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.jack.api.v01.CompilationException

**JAVA version used :** 1.8
**Gradle version used :** gradle-2.14.1
**Android Studio Version** used : 2.2.3

Few Things that have been tried :

1. Adding the jackOption to true.
2. Using Default Gradle wrapper.

Few Stack Overflow questions already seen

1. [Option_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683608/android-jack-lambda-coming-from-jar-file-need-their-interfaces-on-the-classpath)
2. [Option_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230884/why-do-i-get-this-compiler-error-when-i-use-lambda-expressions)
3. [Option_3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211386)

Comment: I am having a similar issue - have you found a solution?